# sar + get network info from sar

Tags: linux, networking, redhat, udp, sar

this syntax give the network info on sa1 file

```
sar -n DEV -f /var/log/sa/sa1
```

how to get the info only from UDP protocol ?

we try also

```
sar -n UDP -f /var/log/sa/sa1
Requested activities not available in file /var/log/sa/sa1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the UDP keyword, statistics about UDPv4 network traffic are reported. Note that UDPv4 statistics depend on sadc option **"-S SNMP"** to be collected. So your command is not showing stats mean stats are not enabled yet, Check if option enabled or not. Not sure which stats you are looking for in UDP one example is given below.

```
$ sar -n SOCK
Linux XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.x86_64 (Myserver)     07/23/2019  _x86_64_    (2 CPU)

12:00:02 AM    totsck    tcpsck    udpsck    rawsck   ip-frag    tcp-tw
12:10:01 AM       282       124         8         1         0       589
12:20:01 AM       288       124         8         1         0       586
12:30:01 AM       291       129         8         1         0       374
12:40:01 AM       296       128        13         1         0       407
12:50:02 AM       301       136         8         1         0       484
01:00:01 AM       292       129         8         0         0       602
01:10:01 AM       304       132         8         1         0       487
01:20:01 AM       294       130         8         1         0       572
01:30:01 AM       293       133         8         1         0       449
01:40:01 AM       293       129        10         1         0       433
01:50:01 AM       308       135         8         1         0       341
02:00:02 AM       303       138         8         0         0       463
02:10:01 AM       305       139         8         1         0       480
02:20:02 AM       306       140         8         1         0       589
02:30:01 AM       300       142         8         1         0       584
02:40:01 AM       306       141         8         1         0       453
02:50:01 AM       309       149         8         1         0       449
03:00:01 AM       316       141         8         1         0       621
03:10:02 AM       288       123         9         1         0       552
03:20:01 AM       287       123         8         1         0       434
03:30:01 AM       293       127         8         1         0       573
03:40:02 AM       296       130        12         1         0       584
03:50:01 AM       314       141         8         1         0       391
Average:          298       133         9         1         0       500
```